# How to do multiple operations in $filter?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, aggregation-framework

```
db.filter_test.aggregate([
    {"$project":{
        "Site_id": "$SITE_ID", 
        "ZIP": "$ZIP", 
        "FIRST_DATE": "$FIRST_DATE",
        "ENTERS": {
            "$filter": {
                "input": "$ENTERS", 
                "as": "item", 
                "cond": {"$gt": [{"$subtract": ["$$item.DATE", "$FIRST_DATE"]}, 2]}
            }
        }
    }},
    {"$out":"filter_output"}
])
```

The $subtract inside the $gt operator seems to be not working. The output is equivalent to `"gt": ["$$item.DATE", 2]`. Is there any work around for this?

Comment: What do you mean by *...not working* ? Is there any traceback you want to share with us? Also you have missing quote in the `$subtract` expression.

Comment: I mean the output I am obtaining is the same as if there was no $subtract operator.